# Get generated entity Id before persisting, Hibernate, Spring data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Some preconditions:

I am not using Oracle DB sequence generator. Instead of it, I rely on the Hibernate sequence generator e.x.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JPA_ENTITY_A")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
public class JpaEntityA{
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(name="NAME_WITH_ID")
    String nameWithGeneratedId;
}
```

What I want is to persist the following generated value into the column "NAME_WITH_ID": `this.nameWithGeneratedId+this.id`

Is it feasible to do the following:

```
public String getNameWithGeneratedId(){
    return this.nameWithGeneratedId+this.id;//hope that the returned value will be persisted
}
```

Or is it possible to retrieve in advance before persisting entity to the DB generated id? If yes, then how can I accomplish it? (based on the comments below it is not possible to do it)

Thx in advance.

Comment: Many other JPA providers make generated values available during `@PrePersist`, so you would be able to access it before the actual INSERT. Seemingly Hibernate doesn't do this. See this issue raised on JPA to make it part of the next version of the spec https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-133

Answer (score 1):

You can't; the act of persisting itself is what creates the ID.

Comment: But the hibernate should generate the unique ID in advance in order to save the entity.

Comment: @mr.M Hibernate can't assume that you're operating only a single instance of your application, and the creation (and assurance of uniqueness) has to be coordinated with the database.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, which uses a UUID generator, I think you can use the [Lifecycle](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/classic/Lifecycle.java) interface and implement the `onSave` method returning `NO_VETO`.

e.g.

```java
@Entity
public MyEntity implements Lifecycle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

   ...


    public boolean onSave(final Session session) throws CallbackException {
      // here your entity will have an ID
      return Lifecycle.NO_VETO;
    }

    ...

}
```

The `onSave` method will be called before saving the entity and after generating the ID.